# How can I get code assist for jQuery within a JSPX file in eclipse?

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse-plugin, jspx, code-assist

I'm trying to edit and add some jQuery functionality to a jspx page and could really use a little code assist for playing with jQuery.  I've installed the aptana plugin and have tried switching to the aptana web perspective but I'm not getting any ctrl+space popups (I've enabled jQuery 1.3 and 1.4 in the eclipse -> aptana -> javascript -> code assist preference).  Is there a way to get aptana to kick in on a jspx file?  Is there another plugin I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following instructions on this website:

http://www.langtags.com/jquerywtp/?page_id=4#comment-59

Which guides you through "patching" one of the wtp jar files...doesn't seem like the best solution, however, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to open your jspx file in the Aptana Html Editor. 
Right click the file -> Open with -> Others... -> Aptana Html Editor. 
Then the code assist should work for your javascript.

Comment: I tried that but the aptana plugin errors out when trying to open the file.